# XPath: select parent node when child propertyvalue starts with value

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to select all parent nodes of type FOO where BAR nodes are childs and the BAR node has a attribute A that starts with X.

e.g.  In the example below, i would like to select FOO (id = A) because i have a BAR with attribute A starting with an X.

```
<rumba>
  <latin>
    <FOO id="A">
      <BAR id="1" A="XYZ" />
      <BAR id="2" A="ABC" />
    </FOO>
  </latin>
  <salsa>
    <FOO id="B">
      <BAR id="3" A="UVW" />
    </FOO>
  </salsa>
</rumba>
```

I am pretty sure this can be done in XPATH, but I can't get my head wrapped around this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//FOO[BAR[starts-with(@A, 'X')]]`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test these but I think they should work.

If your context node is a `BAR` you can use this to find a parent with characteristics you described:

```
../FOO[BAR[starts-with(@A, "X")]]
```

Or if you want to search the entire document for `FOO` nodes that match your criteria you can use:

```
//FOO[BAR[starts-with(@A, "X")]]
```

Comment: The `starts-with()` is incorrect. In XPath 1.0, you'll get an unknown nodetype error. In XPath 2.0, you'll get an error similar to "Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more items starting with a boolean."

Comment: The slash after BAR is causing issues

Comment: @DanielHaley: Thanks for the feedback, I've corrected my answer with the proper syntax.